# can't access wp admin

Tags: wordpress, authentication, wordpress-theming, lwp

I recently purchased a word press theme called https://www.enginethemes.com/themes/forumengine/.

Apparently I didn't know but there is an option to remove the WP-admin access when I reconfigured the theme the first time ( but why would you even put an option like that?)

Anyway apparently I checked this option, so now I cannot access my wp-admin.
And I am the only user. 
When I try to go on mywebsite.com/wp-admin, it takes me to the regular website.

Any idea on how I could fix this?

Thanks a lot

Yann

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the permissions on your wp-admin folder to 755.  It depends on how you put the theme into your wordpress install but the permissions are probably set to your user or root and not www-data or some such.  It's pretty common and you can usually solve this problem with a tiny bit of google fu.